How to splitting code shadcn form component in React/NextJs
I have just started learning Next.js and shadcn, but I am confused about how to split the code in the form component because my code has already reached 4000 lines.
How can I split it to make it shorter by breaking it into smaller components?
source code: https://codefile.io/f/y75KTX89uG

Start by extract the form schema into a separate file
